# How to break the circle of force and mass by other effects?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, mass

Here we will meet the famous logic circle in Newton's second law:

> $$ F = m a $$
> where force is defined by the ability to change the motion of a given mass, and then mass is defined by the resistance to that change.

The conventional method is to measure the force first to break the circle by pulled a spring or any other things.

So my question is following:

> How does one measure or compute the mass of quantum particle first by quantum mechanical effects or any other effects involved the mass? You know you cannot just apply the Newton's mechanical effect but the mass will appear in your dynamical law:
>
> $$i\hbar \partial_t| \psi \rangle = (-\dfrac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2+U) |\psi\rangle$$

Comment: Yes, see dmckee's answer [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/179270/52805).

Comment: Maybe you are interested in reading chapter 14 of Max Jammers book "Concepts of Mass in Classical and Modern Physics" which discusses your question. There is also an interesting article by Franck Wilczek from a modern particle physics point of view: https://www.degruyter.com/downloadpdf/j/phys.2012.10.issue-5/s11534-012-0121-0/s11534-012-0121-0.xml

Comment: I'm not sure what the "logic circle" is here.